# How to convert 0x53797374656d2e427974655b5d to Image format and display tnem using asp handler

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have saved images in my sql table but when i am displaying them using asp.net Image handler some images are broken they are saved in this format `0x53797374656d2e427974655b5d`. I want to Know that
can I convert them to image so that i can display them.

The Handler code:

```
  public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler {

public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    string id = context.Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ToString());
    con.Open(); 
    SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand("select Image from table where xyz=@xyz", con);
    objCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xyz", id.ToString());
    object data = objCmd.ExecuteScalar();
    con.Close();
    objCmd.Dispose();
    if(data == null)
    {
            
    }
    context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])data);
}

public bool IsReusable {
    get {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

In aspx page:

```
  <asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "ImageHandler.ashx?ID=" + Eval("xyz")%>' 
 alt="Image broken"/>
```

Please let me know is there any way that i can convert these images to their original format.

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) [It is evil.](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: In what sense broken? What happens actually? Also, you don't seem to set the Content-type on the response.

Comment: If you consult an ASCII table with a hex column you'll see that your "image bytes", `0x53797374656d2e427974655b5d`, translate to `System.Byte[]`. Looks like you've lost the original image data when trying to persist it to the database.

Comment: That means it cannot be converted to original Image...